# New Api return Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I create asp.Net Core API like, after that I create a controller like this:

```cs
 [Route("api/Email")]
    public class EmailController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;


        public EmailController(IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _emailSender = emailSender;

        }

            [Route("Send")]
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Index(string Email)
            {
                _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Email, "Confirm your account","correo desde api");
                return View();
            }
```

Problem occcurs when I try to execute this path with Postman as:

```
http://localhost:3703/api/Email/Send
```

with JSON raw parameter like:

```
{
    "Email":"myemail@gmail.com"
}
```

It just returns 500 Internal Server Error, I try to put breakpoint into api Send method and it never hitted. I need to do another configuration to execute a simple method of controller? Regards

Comment: Make sure that the `emailSender ` is correctly injected. So put your breakpoint in your constructor.

Comment: No it not be hitted, what am I doing wrong in constructor? did you see something wrong? @CodeNotFound

Comment: Do you have an empty constructor? If so, does the debugger stop in the empty constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment to your question the constructor of your controller is not hitted.

So you need to make sure that the `IEmailSender` is correctly configured for dependency injection.

So in your `Startup` class go to `ConfigureServices` method and add the following line if it not exists:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, MyEmailSenderImplementation>();
```

`MyEmailSenderImplementation` should be the class that impelments `IEmailSender` interface.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to register service in startup. Regards